Getting the first element in multiple divs jQuery
Trying to apply css to the first element in multiple divs with the same class. In the example below, it works in the first div, but not the second one. What's wrong with this picture?
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".axxs-tabs").each(function(){
            $("ul li:first a").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
    });
</script>
    
<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>
    
<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>


As a side note, your each function is useless; you aren't using the result of that iteration.  It's just going to repeat the inner code several times.

That's not very helpful. If I remove that part and just do this: $(".axxs-tabs ul li:first a").css("background-color", "yellow"); it doesn't work either.

What I was trying to point out is the issue mgarcia fixed below.  You needed to use this within the function to use the result of the each.

$(".axxs-tabs ul li:first-child a")

If you want to take into account the ancestor with class axxs-tabs, your selector within the each loop should take into account that element.
You can do so by searching the descendants of that element inside the each block:


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".axxs-tabs").each(function(){
        $(this).find("ul li:first a").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>




Excellent. Thanks much for the assistance.

Just use :first-child selector without .each() function:


$(".axxs-tabs li:first-child>a").css("background-color", "yellow");
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="axxs-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the second paragraph.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the last paragraph.</a>
    </ul>
</div>



